# kali linux stuck with red square

Tags: linux, kali-linux, dual-boot

**Kali stuck with a red square**

[image]

```
kali-linux-2023.3-installer-amd64
```

**System Model:** HP Z420 Workstation

**Processor:**    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 0 @ 3.60GHz   3.60 GHz

**Card name:**    NVIDIA Quadro FX 580

**RAM:**          8.00 GB

sorry, I'm new with Kali Linux.

and when I try to boot with another mode
I get this
[image: recovery]

**Thanks.**

Comment: What happens if you try a different distribution, such as Mint?

Comment: i  used Ubuntu before and it worked fine.

Comment: So maybe stick with Ubuntu? There's no big reason why you can't install the cybersuite tools if that's why you need Kali

Comment: idk, I need something different to start with again and try to fix it and know what is happening.
Thanks for your reply

Comment: Your "boot with another mode" image looks like something is trying to overlap the text-mode display to insert some sort of notification to the top-left corner of the screen, but it gets rendered incorrectly, perhaps because of unexpected display mode. Are you using a KVM switch, and if so, would the missing chunk match its on-screen displays? Alternatively, the workstation does include Intel ME remote management capability, and HP ProtectTools, which may include LoJack Pro anti-theft functionality - are you sure these have not been activated?

Comment: @telcoM thanks for the reply I disconnected KVM and it is still the same, and for ProtectTools it's disabled, is there any chance Nvidia can make this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply I found it is was the GPU and I used nomodeset and it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read about if **GPU** effect because I have only **Nvidia**  then I found some people talk about use `nomodeset` so I looking to know how use it here the link
[From Dell website explaining](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000123893/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting)

1. When grub bootloader open I press `e`
2. Search for `quiet splash` and add `quiet splash nomodeset`
3. Press `CTR + X` or `Esc` to save
4. When kali is starting I install Nvidia driver here the link from [Kali website](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux/)

I hope this help someone too.